# Sort grouped arrays by priority

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Sorry for the bad wording, I can't even formulate it in an amicable way, so I'll describe it with examples.

I have a scope of priorities:

```
const priorities = new Map([
    ['lowest', 1],
    ['low', 2],
    ['high', 3],
    ['highest', 4],
])
```

I have an array of objects with groups and priorities:

```
const array = [
    {id: 1, priority: 'high'},
    {id: 2, priority: 'lowest'},
    {id: 3, priority: 'highest'},
    {id: 4, group: 1, priority: 'low'},
    {id: 5, group: 2, priority: 'low'},
    {id: 6, group: 2, priority: 'lowest'},
    {id: 7, group: 2, priority: 'low'},
    {id: 8, group: 1, priority: 'high'}
];
```

And I have grouped this array to an object with grouped arrays of elements:

```
const groups = {
    0: [{ id: 1, priority: 'high' }, { id: 2, priority: 'lowest' }, { id: 3, priority: 'highest' }], // have no highest priority for group 0
    1: [{ id: 4, group: 1, priority: 'low' }, { id: 8, group: 1, priority: 'high' }], // high
    2: [{ id: 5, group: 2, priority: 'low' }, { id: 6, group: 2, priority: 'lowest' }, { id: 7, group: 2, priority: 'low' }] // low
};
```

The priority of the group *(except group 0)* it's highest priority of the items in this group. I need to pick highest priority from an each group *(except group 0)* to sort groups and items from group 0 from `highest` to `lowest`, it should looks like

```
[<highest by priority item w/o group>, ...<items from highest by priority group>, ... , <lowest by priority items>, <>]
```

At all, I need sort by `group's priority` + `item without group priority` + `initial position`.
E.g. result for the current initial array:

```
const result = [
    { id: 3, priority: 'highest' },
    { id: 1, priority: 'high' },
    { id: 4, group: 1, priority: 'low' },
    { id: 8, group: 1, priority: 'high' },
    { id: 5, group: 2, priority: 'low' },
    { id: 6, group: 2, priority: 'lowest' },
    { id: 7, group: 2, priority: 'low' },
    { id: 2, priority: 'lowest' },
];
```

How I could make it?

Comment: do you want only the lowest of undefined group at the end?

Comment: Why is item 8 (group 1, prio high) not placed before item 4 (group 1, prio low)? Don't you want to sort the items within each (non-0) group by their priority?

Comment: What should happen if two groups have the same (top-of-their-items) priority?

Comment: @Bergi item 8 not placed before item 4 because I do not need to sort items inside group, they should be placed like in the initial array. If two groups have the same priority at first should be placed items from group that contains item which placed closer to start of the initial array

Comment: @NinaScholz not really. e.g. If the lowest item of undefined group placed before one of the items from group with lowest priority in the initial array - it should be placed before the items from the "lowest" group

Comment: do you have some more use cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

- give each item an index, to know their original order. (It might also be possible to rely on sort stability, but it's easier to reason about when being explicit):

  ```
  for (const [i, o] of array.entries()) o.index = i;
  ```
- give each group a key to sort on, which is based on the max priority and first item:

  ```
  const groupIds = Object.keys(groups).filter(g => g != 0);
  groupIds.map(g => {
    let minIndex = Infinity, maxPriority = 0;
    for (const item of groups[g])
      minIndex = Math.min(minIndex, item.index);
      maxPriority = Math.max(maxPriority, priorities.get(item.priority));
    }
    return {group: groups[g], minIndex, maxPriority};
  })
  ```
- add one single-item "group" per ungrouped item:

  ```
  ….concat(groups[0].map(item => {
    return {group: [item], maxPriority: priorities.get(item.priority), minIndex: item.index};
  }))
  ```
- before sorting the array of groups:

  ```
  ….sort((a, b) => b.maxPriority - a.maxPriority || a.minIndex - b.minIndex)
  ```
- and then joining them together into the result:

  ```
  ….flatMap(({group}) => {
    return group.sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index); // might be unnecessary depending on how you built the group arrays
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I needed. Corrected a little for my realization and it works as I expected